# django: trying to organize clean_data functions, and validators. Where does each thing go?

Tags: django, django-validation

I am trying to find the way to organize code snippets the right way but I am getting mixed up with all this:

I have the models.py where I have declared (show part of the fields) this

```
class Posts(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank = True)
```

Then I want to sanitize that field just in case someone wants to be funny in the form page.

So I went to forms.py and created a custom method to clean it

```
class PostsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['image' , 'otherfields']

        def clean_image(self):
            image = self.cleaned_data['image']
```

Ok that cleans it, but I need more, like making sure they dont upload a file too large. So I thought I could create a directory in templates/validators and
create a file like validators.py where I write my validation functions and then I can import that function.

So. validators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import  ValidationError

def file_size(value):
    limit = 2 * 100 * 100
    if value.size > limit:
        raise ValidationError('File too large. Should be less than 200 Kbs')
```

so when I am in the forms.py I wanted to import that file validators.py like this

```
from myaapp.validators import file_size
```

but it tells me that it doesn't know what this "file_size" (unsolved reference in pycharm)

In short, I am completely confused how I have to organize these three things.

Comment: Can you please show you folder tree structure?

Comment: Your `clean_image` method *is* the thing that is supposed to do validation. Just returning the data by itself is pointless, that is what the form does already. (And it does even less when it is nested inside Meta.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case here might be PyCharm, unable to recognize the file. Why don't you move the file to the same directory as models.py and forms.py. Then you can access it by

```
from myapp.validators import file_size
```

Also while using custom validators you should provide the validator to be used in both model and form classes.

```
# models.py
from myapp.validators import file_size


class Posts(models.Model):
   image = models.ImageField(validators=[file_size])

#forms.py
from myapp.validators import file_size


class PostsForm(ModelForm):
    image = forms.imageField(validators=[file_size])
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['image' , 'otherfields']

        def clean_image(self):
            image = self.cleaned_data['image']
```

Refer [Writing Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/).

If you are not using the validator in multiple scenarios, just once. It's better to provide the validation in form class itself.

Comment: The indentation in your code is broken.  I can't edit it because it requires less than 6 characters of change.  :(

Comment: @AdamBarnes Sorry for the trouble. I was editing it from my mobile. Will try to keep in check from next time. 